# Writing a big text file fast

Tags: java, android, filewriter, printwriter, bufferedwriter

How can I write a big text file very fast on Android?
I made some tests using a PrintWriter, a BufferedWriter and a FileWriter, but there are no significative time difference, and writing takes about three times the time of reading.

Comment: I guess this as fast as you can get. Read vs write speeds are also restricted by the used hardware technology.

Comment: `BufferedWriter` should increase the performance - if not, you can play with `BufferedWriter(Writer out, int sz)` constructor

Answer (score 1):

Android, just like every single other device with a storage unit, has limited writing speed.

The only thing you can do to speed up file writing and reading is get a better storage unit (which isn't as easy on an Android device as you can't just screw it open and replace the unit).

So when it comes to file reading and writing, you're limited by hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Each memory has a specific block and page size. Due to how writes are done on Flash memories, it matters if you write it in small chunks.

Here is a benchmark with `dd` run in `adb shell`:

```
sailfish:/storage/emulated/0 $ dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=4k count=$((32*1024))                                                                                                                                                                                              
32768+0 records in
32768+0 records out
134217728 bytes transferred in 0.521 secs (257615600 bytes/sec)
```

Another one for 1k block:

```
sailfish:/storage/emulated/0 $ dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=1k count=$((128*1024))                                                                                                                                                                                           
131072+0 records in
131072+0 records out
134217728 bytes transferred in 1.369 secs (98040707 bytes/sec)
```

Writing data in small chunks makes it almost 3x slower.
I encourage you to benchmark your memory to see if you hit a hardware limitation. Experiment with write buffer sizes. If your memory is genuinely slower during writes, there is nothing more you can do.

Answer (score 0):

For faster `file` read/write take a look at [java.nio](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) package.

This is a good [article](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/nio-vs-io.html) about java `NIO`, here you can find comparison with `IO` package

Answer (score 0):

Give [Okio](https://github.com/square/okio) a spin. Not sure if it's actually faster though.